# Could not load the image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging

I deleted a lot of images off my project that I no longer use anymore. Now in the log, I get a bunch of

Could not load the "Sending.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.mystuff.hello"

the images that I deleted from the project but I no longer use. The app functions correctly, but I get all of these warnings in the log that I want to get rid of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have images referenced from nib files that you no longer use. If that is the case, removing those unused nib files would fix the issue.